# How to get an IEnumerable of child objects that can have child objects

Tags: c#, ienumerable, children

In C#, how is the best way to get an `IEnumerable<T>` of all child objects, where a child object can have a child?

Here is an example:

I have a class called `Test`, with the following ids:

```
int id

int parentId
```

I have a `List<Test>` called `testItems` that is populated with many Test objects.

Each `Test` object, has an `id`, and can have a `parentId` of another `Test` object in the `List`.

If I have an `id`, how is the best way to get an `IEnumerable<Test>` that has all childs including childs of childs?

Here is some more information:

I have the following Test Objects:

- a
- b
- c
- d
- a has no parent
- b has a parent of a
- c has a parent of b
- d has a parent of c

If I have the id of b, how can I get an `IEnumerable` that contains all children of c. This `IEnumerable` will contain c and d.

Thanks.

Comment: As it stands, your `Test` class is arguably not OO having no _"child objects"_ merely IDs.  Aren't you missing `List<Test>` as a member somewhere?  Please post your entire class definition

Comment: I have the List<Test> that is populated with Test objects.

Comment: OK, but is that the _root container_ somewhere else or does each `Test` have that member?  As I said, please post your _entire_ definition

Comment: The root container is somewhere else, stored as a List.

Comment: It may be better idea to build tree (O(n) using dictionary of nodes by id) and than walk the tree down (O(n))... otherwise searching for child nodes every time would be very slow.

Comment: Oh _that_ is what you are trying to do.  Why do that?  Not a particularly efficient data structure

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this:

```
IEnumerable<Test> AllChildren(List<Test) list,Test mytest)
{
  foreach(var test in list)
  {
    if (test.parentid==mytest.id)
    {
       yield return test;
       foreach(var t in AllChildren(list,test))
       {
         yeild return t;
       }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: It is.  You could make it faster, if necessary.  Build a dictionary or some such, but don't optimize what doesn't need to be.